# internalViewResolver not working in

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have started with spring MVC. but my internalViewReolver returning just string instead of resolving page from my path. Please help me out where did I go wrong?

Here's my config file.:

```
package assignment.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"assignment.view"})
public class WebConifg extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {

        configurer.enable();;
    }
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver("/WEB-INF/views/",".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);

        return resolver;

    }
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
package assignment.view;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import assignment.model.User;

@RestController(value="/login")
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String userLogin(@RequestBody User user){
    System.out.println(user);
    return "success";
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(Model model){
    User user=new User();
    model.addAttribute("userForm", user);
    System.out.println(user);
    return "Register";
}
}
```

My WebIntilizer.java

```
package assignment.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebInitilizer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

        return new Class<?>[]{WebConifg.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {

        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

So when I hit http://localhost:8080/assignment/login I expected to  show Register.jsp but it just showed Register as a string.

Comment: Use Controller annotation in place of RestController annotation. May Help.

Comment: You tried the solutin?? its work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your annotation from RestController to Controller annotation.

It will work for sure.

When you use RestController annotation the web app will send response in text format like simple text (your case), json, xml.

Comment: @LowCool if it does not help please let me know. I will try to help.

Comment: It worked..can you please tell me exact difference between this 2??

Comment: @LowCool when you say your are using RestController annotation, so automatically implies that response will be in text format as I said.

Comment: Its internal implementation that RestController means their will be no html response.

Comment: @LowCool could you please up-vote also if it helped you :))